# Store SQL query results as $string

Tags: mysql, loops

I bet this is loop 101 but here it goes.  I am only getting the results printed to screen since, of course, that's what I'm using in the code (i.e. echo) but I want to save what is printed as an actual string.  I do not want it to show up but simply be passed.

This is normally a piece of cake for me but this is a nested loop which is confusing me.  Currently this is the results printed to screen.  "Qty: 1 - 2" Designer Wood Blinds | Qty: 2 - 2" Designer Wood Blinds | Qty: 3 - 2" Designer Wood Blinds |"  which is perfect format and everything.  I want that as a $string that I can pass onto the shopping cart description.

What do I replace the "echo" parts of the script with?  Thank you from a very loopy mind.

```
$desc_details = mysql_query("SELECT qty, prodid FROM cartitems WHERE uniquetoken = '".$uniquetoken."';");
while($detail_list = mysql_fetch_array($desc_details))
{
    echo "Qty: " .$detail_list['qty']. " - ";

            $desc_prodid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodid = '".$detail_list['prodid']."';");
            while($detail_prod = mysql_fetch_array($desc_prodid))
               {
                  echo $detail_prod['prodname']. " | ";
               }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str='';
$desc_details = mysql_query("SELECT qty, prodid FROM cartitems WHERE uniquetoken = '".$uniquetoken."';");
while($detail_list = mysql_fetch_array($desc_details))
{
    $str.= "Qty: " .$detail_list['qty']. " - ";

            $desc_prodid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodid = '".$detail_list['prodid']."';");
            while($detail_prod = mysql_fetch_array($desc_prodid))
               {
                  $str.= $detail_prod['prodname']. " | ";
               }
};
```

$str will store your data as string

Comment: This is perfect!  What does the .= do so I understand for future reference?  I imagine the . is what joins the strings together?  Also, I felt inclined to give you the correct answer even though all 3 were correct answers because you showed to start off with $str="" in the beginning part and actually showed it inserted into the code.  Thank you for that.

Comment: $str.=$any_var is the shortcut for the statement $str=$str.$any_val where . is the operator in php used to join two string in php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert myself but have you tried something along the lines of like `$string .=` (string concatenation) instead of `echo`?

And then you can echo $string where you need it specifically.

Answer (score -1):

When in need of a string, concat it.

```
$desc_details = mysql_query("SELECT qty, prodid FROM cartitems WHERE uniquetoken = '".$uniquetoken."';");
$string;
while($detail_list = mysql_fetch_array($desc_details)) {
    $string .= "Qty: " .$detail_list['qty']. " - ";

          $desc_prodid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodid = '".$detail_list['prodid']."';");
          while($detail_prod = mysql_fetch_array($desc_prodid))
            {
               $string .= $detail_prod['prodname']. " | ";
            }
};
```

Note the addition of $string.